# Problem with shell extentions on windows web server 2008 64bit?

Tags: tortoisesvn, windows

I've tried to install TortoiseSVN (twice) in my 64 bit Windows Web Server 2008 RS installation, but the shell extention isn't showing at all. Anone knowing of a problem with shell extention in this version of windows?

Comment: The tortoise SVN site seems to be linking incorrectly to 32bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might seem like an obvious question.  But did you install the 64-bit version of TortoiseSVN?  32-bit shell extensions won't work in a 64-bit shell.  You also need to reboot the box for the shell extension to load.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I insalled the 64bit version and I've restarted. But I will try again.